# Two conditions - which will be first

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to wait for 500 ms and "listen" for some changes. If there are no changes then execute first method, if there were some changes - execute another.

 How can I do this?

Comment: Elaborate on what you have done.

Comment: you could just let angular handle it with `$scope.$watch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `setTimeout` in vanilla javascript.

```
setTimeout(function(){
   if(thereWereChanges){
      DoSomething();
   }
   else{
      DoSomethingElse();
   }
},500);
```

The same with angular would be

```
$timeout(function(){
   if(thereWereChanges){
      DoSomething();
   }
   else{
      DoSomethingElse();
   }
},500)
```

Comment: Better use `$timeout` for that

Comment: @MartijnWelker I didnt even spot the angular tag. Thanks. Updated.

Comment: But it won't listen for changes during this time, only after timeout ends - right?